# What does 0x400 mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

In the instruction "movl $0x400,%eax" Does $0x400 refer to the address or the hexadecimal value of the number?

Comment: The `$` means immediate. So it's a number. It's not a property of `0x400` itself. If you wrote `mov 0x400, %eax` (without the `$`) it would be a read from memory at address 0x400.

Comment: `0x400` is a numeric literal.  Your question title left out the `$` that's necessary in that context (as an instruction operand) to indicate an immediate instead of a memory operand.

Comment: Okay, I got it; thanks a lot for the response.